# How to know whether the verb takes both accusative and dative objects or only an accusative object?

Tags: verb-usage

> Ich gebe meinem Vater das Zeugnis ab.

oder

> Ich gebe das Zeugnis bei meinem Vater ab.

It seems both are correct. Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 3):

> Ich gebe meinem Vater das Zeugnis (ab).
>
> Ich gebe das Zeugnis bei meinem Vater ab.

Both are correct. If the verb action means passing something, you can be pretty sure it's possible (or even required) to use a dative object. It acts as *the receiver* of the accusative object then. It's one of the very few case functions in German with a simple usage rule. You can even extend this to verbs with a lonely dative object as

> Ich helfe meinem Vater.

which you can think of as

> Ich gebe meinem Vater Hilfe.

In both cases, *meinem Vater* is the receiver of help.

Comment: _If the verb action means passing something, you can be pretty sure it's possible (or even required) to use a dative object_ I admit I didn't see this rule. But it is true: _überlassen_, _hinterlassen_, _schenken_, _übergeben_, _aushändigen_, _verkaufen_, and so on and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are correct, but the first one is less correct in terms of style. ONe would rather say

> Ich gebe das Zeugnis meinem Vater.

You cannot know this from a rule. There is no other way than learning the valences (i.e which objects in which cases a verb does accept) of a verb together with the meaning of the verb. It is part of the vocabulary, and I think there is no general rule which verb will accept which cases and which prepositions. Though, the prepositions themselves are rather stable in the case they demand.

Just as a side note: In your example, both *bei meinem Vater* and *meinem Vater* are dative (Dativ) case!

Comment: Well, *geben* is the archetype of verbs that take a dative object. The dative object often enough is *the receiver* of the accusative object, and *geben* obviously needs a receiver.

Comment: @Janka: I'm not really sure, whether *abgeben* also asks for a dative object. All examples I found use *bei*, *an* or similar.

Comment: @Janka Fair enough, since _Dativ_ literally means the giving case". But anyway, I'd claim that you should better learn the cases for the verbs, since guessing might not lead to good results.

Comment: @guidot _Ich gebe dir etwas von meinem Essen ab._

Comment: Thats the difference between meaning (a) and (d) of [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/abgeben). I had assumed meaning a from the admittedly terse question.